# Feature-request : provide a way to link to a comment's source text file

Tags: feature-request

This is just a simple(I think) idea.  Sometimes, there are comments that we may want to share. Of course, I realize that comments are 2nd-hand citizens, and all the rest.

I just am looking for a back-end way, not publicly available, to link to a comment's source text. This way, when you click the link , it just opens a "dead-end" page with the comment on it.  Maybe like this :

[image]

Is this possible? I guess you can retrieve comments via a database query, but it would be neat if there was a known way to reference comment text.

This would be useful so that perhaps sometimes you want to keep track of someone's useful comment, and want to keep a link of it.

Because this is a lesser-used feature, it wouldn't change the UI at all or require a need for a special button (knowing that the space is already cramped with an 'upvote' and a 'flag' taking up all available space). Just an easter-egg type feature.

Someone may say that we already can link to answers, but again - just a matter of convenience/ simplicity.

Comment: If a comment is "useful", why isn't it captured in something that's significantly less temporal, like a question or answer?

Comment: @Makoto There are occasionally (actually not that rare, sadly), cases where the best answer to a bad question that isn't receiving any answers is in the comments. I see it quite commonly nowadays because people are reluctant to answer bad questions or borderline-off topic ones, so a lot of QA and sometimes even the greatest answer is found in the comments in those cases. That said, I don't fully understand the point of this proposal that much.

Comment: @Ike: That's actually not how comments were intended to be used, and is actively dangerous in that the comment could disappear at any moment.  Now, if the question is bad or off topic, it shouldn't be answered until it's improved or brought on topic.

Comment: @Makoto `"it shouldn't be answered until it's improved or brought on topic"` -- yeah, that's why I think I'm seeing these trends where I find lots of good answers in comments instead of answers. It's a symptom of all these bad questions.

Comment: What I tend to find is, for example, a lot of cases where you have this borderline off-topic question. It has 1 close vote along with a -1 or -2 rating. Then 3 speed shooters fire off answers, typically with reps close to my range or below firing best-guess answers, or maybe the author has two problems and they give half-answers for the obvious one. Then you have this great conscientious, experienced user with anywhere ranging from like 20k or higher rep and he knows not to answer, but to comment. And then the best and most complete answer ends up being found in the comment for that question.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I get a link to a comment?

> Sometimes you want to keep track of someone's useful comment, and want to keep a link of it.

The following is not a complete answer your question (as it doesn't provide the *comment's source text*) but it does allow you to save the links for future reference.

You can already get a link to a comment. The comment "time" is a link:

[image]

[Feature-request : provide a way to link to a comment's source text file](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310596/feature-request-provide-a-way-to-link-to-a-comments-source-text-file/310617#comment272859_310596)

Notes:

- Comments are second class citizens and can be deleted/purged at any time...
- So it is probably better to saving anything you might want to keep somewhere else, for example in a file of useful notes ...

Comment: @Cerbrus OP asks "sometimes you want to keep track of someone's useful comment, and want to **keep a link of it.**" - I agree it doesn't give the *source behind the link* - but it does provide a partial answer to his question.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for the observation though, I've expanded the answer a bit to make it clear it's not a full answer.